# Windows spooler reports "paper probleᶆ"

Tags: windows-10, printer, paper

Windows reports "paper problem" for my Dell C1760NW printer:

[image: Paper problem reported by Windows]

However, the printer status on the HTTP website of the printer does not indicate an issue:

[image: HTTP status normal]

I have tried:

- turning the printer off and on
- taking the paper out of the printer and re-inserting it
- cancelling the print job and print again

To me it seems that Windows does not corretly update the status. I ran out of paper on Thursday last week. But since then, I have added paper and I turned off the PC over weekend.

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the printer via the control panel helped.

[image: Uninstall button]